# Slow Python discord.py script

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Does anybody know why this python script is so slow?

It starts to become slow when I start to call the await member.remove_roles() and await member.add_roles(). When I comment the await member.remove_roles() and await member.add_roles() then the performance seems to look ok.

Some background what I want to accomplish.
User subscribe via a website. This data is stored into a mysql DB. Based on the subscription they got a user role assigned.
Base on that user role I would like to assign the same role on a Discord server.

Thx

```
import asyncio
import discord
import mysql.connector
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# Load environment variables from .env file
load_dotenv()

# Discord bot token
BOT_TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
DISCORD_SERVER_ID = os.getenv("DISCORD_SERVER_ID")


# Connect to the MySQL database
db_host = os.getenv("DB_HOST")
db_user = os.getenv("DB_USER")
db_password = os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD")
db_name = os.getenv("DB_NAME")

db_connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    host=db_host,
    user=db_user,
    password=db_password,
    database=db_name
)
db_cursor = db_connection.cursor()

# Create a Discord client
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

async def updateActiveMemberRoles():
    print('def executing')
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    # Get all the members in the guild
    guild = client.get_guild(913107079605141525)  # Replace with the ID of your Discord guild (SERVER ID)

    while not client.is_closed():
        
        ROLE_GOLD    = guild.get_role(991694541298090059)
        ROLE_BRONZE  = guild.get_role(914277751719096381)
        ROLE_VISITOR = guild.get_role(914280052424859700)

        for member in guild.members:
            DiscordName = member.name+"#"+member.discriminator
            print(DiscordName)

            db_cursor.execute("select membership_level from vw_discord_active_members where usrAccount = %s", (DiscordName,))
            result = db_cursor.fetchone()

            if result:
                print(DiscordName+" "+result[0])
            
                membership_level = result[0]
                if membership_level == "gold":
                    await member.remove_roles(ROLE_VISITOR)
                    await member.add_roles(ROLE_BRONZE)
                    await member.add_roles(ROLE_GOLD)
                    print("gold")
                elif membership_level == "bronze":
                    await member.remove_roles(ROLE_VISITOR)
                    await member.remove_roles(ROLE_GOLD)
                    await member.add_roles(ROLE_BRONZE)
                    print("bronze")
            else: 
                await member.remove_roles(ROLE_BRONZE)
                await member.remove_roles(ROLE_GOLD)
                await member.add_roles(ROLE_VISITOR)
                print("visitor")
                
        print("------------------------------")
        print("--- Wait 60 Seconds ----------")
        print("------------------------------")
        await asyncio.sleep(60)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready.")
    client.loop.create_task(updateActiveMemberRoles())


client.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you’re trying to iterate through every single member in the server, then fetch data from an online db that your program has to connect to over the internet. Depending on how good your internet connection is, this could become slow and when you have to do this for every single member on the server it could take some time.

Im pretty sure each role has a list of members with that role so the best way to go about it would be to probably just use a for loop for `role.members` then remove members that contain that role.

Here’s how you use it in the [documentation.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=role%20members#discord.Role)